# remote administration of IBM APP Connect using IBM integration console command line

Tags: integration, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

I am just wondering if for IIB 10 or ACE 12, is it possible to -

1. install IBM integration console command line on a system where ACE is not installed ? if yes, how ?
2. connect to remote integration node using integration console command line, if yes how ?

in either case what are the option for remote administration of ACE from a system where ACE is not installed ?

thanks in advance.

just all option but they didn't seem to work, documentation has no information as well